# How to deploy Phonegap app to iPhone without having Apple hardware (iPhone + Mac)

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, cordova

I have a Phonegap app which works perfectly in Android. I chose Phonegap as a platform mainly because the same code can be used for Android, iPhone, etc.. My question is though, how can I create iPhone app without actually having Apple hardware (iPhone + Mac) as I am having Windows notebook and HTC Desire HD and I am happy with it :-) My app for iPhone will be free so there is no possibility the app itself with compensate for the money for Apple HW. 
 Can you please sum up some options I have how to deploy ready Phonegap app for iPhone ? Or what is the cheapest real option - e.g. buy used iPhone and some kind of used Mac ?

Comment: For as far as I know you can only compile i-phone apps on MAC-OS, which can not be run under windows. So a used macbook seems the most value option

Comment: if you want to install OS X on pc you could install hackingtos(iatkos) and then instal Xcode to have access to simulator. Basically Iatkos is a hacked map operating system(PS be carefull whitch version you install some of them don't have network drivers)

Comment: There is a way to deploy applications on your iPhone, iPod using TestAppFlight without MAC and jail breaking your device. Check my post for details.

Comment: @NikhilMishra *Mac* = Apple Computer | _MAC_ = Media Access Control. ;)

Comment: @Nathan- I messed up with CamelCase at lot of places. Focus on content.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do it by compiling in the cloud with PhoneGap Build.

Check https://build.phonegap.com/

Comment: Wow, thanks for answer, it was very helpful, I didn't have any idea about this service. It looks promising even in Beta mode.

Comment: @Syed Absar, this is false according to the docs. You need a mac to configure the build process.

Comment: There is a way to deploy applications on your iPhone, iPod using TestAppFlight without MAC. Check my post for details.

Comment: following the link i found: "To prepare your certificate, you will need to open the Keychain Access utility on your Mac, and identify the certificate that you use for iOS development."

Comment: Also, you have to use some Apple software called 'Application Loader' to upload to the App Store. It it no longer wholly done via the iTunes Connect website.

Answer (score 12):

Looking at the PhoneGap Cloud page here:

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/ios-builds

it mentions this :

"Note: Since PhoneGap Build uses Apple's standard development process to build applications, you will need to sign up for their developer program to build iOS applications on PhoneGap Build. **You will also need a Mac to configure your certificate and provisioning profile**."

I presume that this is a once-off thing to set up - i.e. you need to "borrow" a mac from somewhere if you don't have one.  Does anyone know if this is correct?

Comment: At the minimum, you'll need to borrow a friend's Mac on two occasions, for a couple of hours each time.

Comment: ..and pay $99 for their developer program?

Comment: Yes, you need to join the program. They won't even let you read some of the documentation until you do!

Comment: Now it can be done with win: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/signing_signing-ios.md.html#_windows_users

Answer (score 6):

Here is tutorial on [How to build iOS application using Windows and OpenSSL](https://nickalchemist.wordpress.com/iapproach-mobile-development-made-elegant/deploying-to-iphone-without-a-mac-with-an-apple-developer-account-and-phonegap-build/). You just need an Apple developer account.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [hackintosh](http://www.hackintosh.com/) in the past in order to simulate a Mac and installed Xcode to build the project for the iOs devices.

The other cheap options are get a Mac mini & a ipod touch.

Answer (score 2):

You still need a Mac to create p12 bundle which is needed for PhoneGap build.

[Mobundler.com](http://mobundler.com) is a service which lets you create iOS p12 bundle as well as Java keystore for Android. Mobundler can be used in conjunction with PhoneGap build to achieve this.

Comment: Seems a little insecure if they're making your Java keystore instead of you yourself.

Comment: Granted it is a convenience tool. Once keystore is generated and downloaded, clicking 'Start over' deletes the keystore from the server.

Comment: Mobundler was so much nicer than just reading the instructions on how to create a .p12 file myself (on Windows or Mac!). I don't really see how they can abuse their 'powers' anyway...?

Comment: Help! Mobundler website has closed down.

Answer (score 2):

You could try rent a Mac on this cloud service:
http://www.macincloud.com

This way, you don't need actual Mac hardware to build your app - only pay/rent when you need to build. However, in the long run it might not be economical.

Answer (score 1):

Marmalade SDK is the all Windows end to end solution that I am happy with. Right from compile to deploy everything is in your control and on windows - No server side compiles or sending zip files around waiting for someone to send you back files that you could deploy on IOS.

But you have to like using Visual Studio C++ ...

Comment: ...which no-one likes. ;-)