# Cross platform app deployment & testing without buying devices

Tags: cross-platform

I have developed an app in android studio i would like to make it cross platform just dont know how to test my app on windows, apple and other devices in the market. So still have not been able to choose the cross platform cloud OR cross platform IDE yet. Can some one share their experience if they have done this or any alternative process for developing - testing - deploying without device?

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, but I would suggest searching for a mobile virtual machine - either one that can be used on a mobile device or on a computer.

[Here](http://www.wired.com/2012/03/vmware-on-the-iphone/) is an interesting article about VMware. Maybe it can give some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still searching though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best answer i could found.

Check out this [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339945/how-to-deploy-phonegap-app-to-iphone-without-having-apple-hardware-iphone-mac) has shed load of information that is indeed useful.